# Pandas, replace rows by mean over given columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm pretty new to Pandas and unfortunately at the moment I don't have much time to dig into it as I would like.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   x  y  z  class     id  other-numeric-field
0  8  8  5      1  1014f             0.388640
1  2  3  4      0  3ba1d             0.431008
2  5  1  6      1  1014f             0.388640
3  7  9  6      1  1014f             0.388640
4  6  9  1      0  7a5d7             0.476972
```

I'd like to replace all rows with the same `class` with their mean over `['x', 'y', 'z']` columns.

Dataframe can contain other columns, numeric or not, which are usually all equal over the same class but that I don't really care to lose if they are not. I could keep the first occurrence or just average over them too if it works with non numeric field also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for `agg` i.e

```
ndf = df.groupby('class').agg({'x':'mean','y':'mean','z':'mean','id':'first','other-numeric-field':'first'})

          id  other-numeric-field         x         z  y
class                                                   
0      3ba1d             0.431008  4.000000  2.500000  6
1      1014f             0.388640  6.666667  5.666667  6
```

To apply this only for class zero, one approach is appending i.e

```
ndf = df.groupby('class',as_index=False).agg({'x':'mean','y':'mean','z':'mean','id':'first','other-numeric-field':'first'})

sdf = df[df['class'].ne(0)].append(ndf[ndf['class'].eq(0)],ignore_index=True)

 class     id  other-numeric-field    x  y    z
0      1  1014f             0.388640  8.0  8  5.0
1      1  1014f             0.388640  5.0  1  6.0
2      1  1014f             0.388640  7.0  9  6.0
3      0  3ba1d             0.431008  4.0  6  2.5
```

Comment: Thanks, approving this one, exactly what I needed. Now if I may, let's say I want to apply this only to class `0`. Would it be possible to do it in the same concise way? I mean apply this to one class and leave the rest untouched

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: guess I'm learning more pandas like this than all the time I spent looking at the docs, thank you

Answer (score 5):

Is that what you want?

```
In [18]: df[['x','y','z']] = df.groupby('class')[['x','y','z']].transform('mean')

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
          x  y         z  class     id  other-numeric-field
0  6.666667  6  5.666667      1  1014f             0.388640
1  4.000000  6  2.500000      0  3ba1d             0.431008
2  6.666667  6  5.666667      1  1014f             0.388640
3  6.666667  6  5.666667      1  1014f             0.388640
4  4.000000  6  2.500000      0  7a5d7             0.476972
```

Comment: yes, thank you! something like that but I'd like to keep all the columns that were in the original dataframe

Comment: read_clipboard, run code , paste results done in less 2 mins : )

Comment: amazing :-) now I'd like to just squeeze the rows with the same mean into a single one, keeping all the columns but not caring if they differ (or just assume they are the same and equal to the first occurrence). Sorry, maybe this wasn't that clear in the question